# Accessing buttons in a table using accessibility labels

Tags: ios

[image]

I need a way to get a reference to each button in the calendar so I can alter its background image whenever I want. I want to do:

```
UIButton *button = [get_reference_to_button_using_Accessibility_label];
[button setBackgroundImage:image]
```

When I initialize the buttons, I set the buttons' accessibility labels. Can I use them to get a reference to each button and change its background color?

```
 for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < self.daysInWeek; index++) {
        NSString *title = [self.dayFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        NSString *accessibilityLabel = [self.accessibilityFormatter stringFromDate:date]; // I can probably use it to refer to this button??
        [self.dayButtons[index] setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.dayButtons[index] setAccessibilityLabel:accessibilityLabel];
        NSLog(@"day buttons!! %@", self.dayButtons[index]);

        ...
```

Comment: Do you know the accessibility label that you're looking for?

Comment: Or just check the titleLabel text for a quick reference.

Comment: Yes, assume that I have the accessibility label. So given an accessibility label(in this case, a string format of NSDate) can I get a cell button object that corressponds to that accessibility label?

Comment: @IanMacDonald is it possible to get a reference to the button using an accessibility label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use `date` to generate a unique (for your calendar) integer in your initializer, and then use that to set a tag on the view?

```
NSInteger myTag = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
[self.dayButtons[index] setTag:myTag];
```

Then when you want to reference the button, all you need is its associated date:

```
UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:[date timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it might work? But is it possible to get a reference to the button like that using an accessibility label?

Comment: I don't know how you'd use the accessibility label to get the view, short of either looping over all the views and testing for the string in question, or associating views and labels in a dictionary that you store in a property. Using a tag seems more elegant and concise, in my opinion.